# prove that a sequence that tends to a limit, multiplied by n, the sequence will be kl.

Tags: proof-writing

Prove that if a sequence $s_n$ goes to a limit L as $n \rightarrow \infty $, then for a number $k >  0 $ then the sequence ${kn}$ will tend to the limi $kl$. 
 Is this simply because k is isolated from the limit, meaning that k has nothing to do with the converging part itself? moreover, how do I prove this?

Answer (score 0):

$|k\cdot s_n-k \cdot l|=k|s_n-l|\rightarrow 0  $

Comment: use \cdot instead of . to get expressions like $a \cdot b$ instead of $a.b$

Comment: can you please give a little explanation? how come it goes to zero?

Comment: what does it mean to say $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }s_n =l$ mean?